# Firebase signInWithPopup creates account when reauthenticating

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-authentication

When reauthenticating a Firebase user via the Google provider for a protected action (password reset, email change, acct deletion, etc), I notice that it creates an account if one doesn't already exist.

The problem this creates is that if a person is signed into multiple Google accounts on their machine and they select the wrong account at re-auth, Firebase will create an account and sign the user in under that account.

This could be particularly problematic at account deletion.  The user expects to *remove* an account only to end up *adding* another.  Also, things like TOS/privacy policy acceptance would then have to be moved to the sign in flow which means users would have to create an account, verify email, and sign in before being presented with terms and policies.

Is there any way to prevent a provider pop-up from creating an account and just return an error if the account chosen for reauth does not match the currently selected account?  I thought about implementing this manually but the problem is that once the user signs in, the old token is removed from storage.  Even if you store the initial email address and compare it to the address selected for reauth, you can't give the user the option to try again because they've already been unauthenticated from the original account and your only option is to sign them out entirely.  This just makes for a tricky elevated auth flow.

Comment: You can still delete() any newly created accidental account. As you would be just authenticated, you shouldn't have any restrictions to delete that account.

Comment: @bojeil - Deleting the accidental enrollment isn't the problem.  If the user has unintentionally authenticated under a new account, the action they were trying to take on the original account can't be executed.  If I immediately delete the accidental account, they'll be signed out and will be under the impression that their original account and data were deleted when in fact they were not.

Comment: Fair point. I think this a Firebase Auth issue. I will file a bug for this via Firebase channels. I think in this case, any accidental account created during reauthentication should be deleted on the Firebase end.